# How to get first child that has been uploaded to Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase Storage set up that has MANY unique files with names that are unpredictable.

Basically I just need to get the VERY first file (child) and I won't be able to reference it by name because the name will be completely different each time.

How do I get the first child, aka first file uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK, as it currently has no API to list files (however, server SDKs can list files, but not sorted by date).

Instead, for each file you upload to Storage, you should also record it to a database, along with a timestamp or whatever data you want to use to determine which file is "first".  Query the database to figure out which is first, then fetch the file.

Comment: Can I delete the file after I am done using it?

Is there any other option? I was specifically trying to avoid the database stuff.

Also I read somewhere else that Cloud Storage now does have an API to list files (since 2017) but that could be wrong I guess

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you want with the file.  You won't be able to avoid the database, as it's the only way you can determine which file is "first".  As I said in my answer, there is a list api for server SDKs, but you can't use that in the client.

Comment: Hello, Doug. I have successfully implemented my database, and now I am receiving a snapshot of it... I want to iterate through the snapshot for each item and get the value + the child value... I am having troubles with that now.

Comment: That sounds like it should be a new post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I mean yeah maybe. The docs say to use Iterable<DataSnapshot> yet that is for java code not C#. Could you just help me instead of making me make a brand new question? No one would even read it for several hours.

Comment: I got myself on the right track, 

DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                
                foreach(var obj in snapshot.Children)
                {
                    Debug.LogFormat("Key = {0}", obj.Key);
                    foreach(var child in obj.Children)
                    {
                        Debug.LogFormat("Key = {0}", child.Key);
                    }
                }